# Android set menu action visibility

Tags: android, toolbar

I have `Activity` and a `Fragment` with a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Can I show menu item "action" after creating menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` by making it visible or something ?

(After clicking custom button for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I show menu item "action" after creating menu in
>   onCreateOptionsMenu() by making it visible or something ?

[yes by overriding `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) : ***Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.*** you make action item visible or gone like below(just sample code).

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuItem menuItemVadd = menu.findItem(R.id.action_vadd);
     if (isShowVisualAdd1) {
            menuItemVadd.setVisible(true);
     } else {
            menuItemVadd.setVisible(false);
     }
     return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) to modify the menu just before it's displayed when the user clicks the menu button.  As stated by the javadoc:

> This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.